# Dynamic radio button doesn't wrap_content

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I have created a radio button with a custom drawable like this.
[image]

I used my custom selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/est_status_radio_checked" android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/est_status_radio_checked" android:state_checked="true" android:state_enabled="false" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/est_status_radio_unchecked" android:state_checked="false" /></selector>
```

with the radio button like the following

```
  <style name="AppTheme.StatusRadioButtons">
    <item name="fontPath">fonts/SFUIText-Semibold.ttf</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/establishment_status_selector</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/est_status_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:button">@null</item>
</style>

  <RadioButton
                    style="@style/AppTheme.StatusRadioButtons"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Stopped" />
```

Everything works fine , but now the requirement is to create dynamic buttons.
For some reason when i create a dynamic radio button , the drawable appears stretched :@ [image]

I have created the button like this

```
private RadioButton createRadioForStatus(EstablishmentStatus establishmentStatus) {
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getContext());
    radioButton.setCompoundDrawablePadding(0);
    radioButton.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
    radioButton.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(),R.drawable.establishment_status_selector));
    radioButton.setButtonDrawable(null);
    radioButton.setTextSize(10);
    radioButton.setElevation(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.unit_small));
    radioButton.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));// wrap content buttons are working perfectly in xml but for some motherfucking reason are not wrapping the content properly when done programatically
    radioButton.setText(establishmentStatus.getName());
    return radioButton;
}
```

My selector drawable is like this

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        <corners android:radius="30dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item
    android:bottom="5dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="55dp"
    android:top="5dp">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
        <size
            android:width="10dp"
            android:height="10dp"></size>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: show the code of establishment_status_selector

Comment: @Ankita I just did a moment ago .

Comment: what is EstablishmentStatus class?

Comment: Its a POJO. I use it to fill the radio button text

Answer (score 0):

You should set your src of radio-button in separate directory and then find it by R

Comment: I will follow you advice and create a seperate xml for the buttom template and inflate it via the layoutinflator. I am however really pissed off at android's general discrepancies that I come across many a times. Things that a developer assumes would work , never do when taking a conventional route. not a place to rant this is though .

Answer (score 0):

Your `RadioButton` should be inside the same `RadioGroup`, Something like this:

```
    RadioGroup radioGroup = new RadioGroup(this);
    RadioButton radioButton1= new RadioButton(this);
    RadioButton radioButton2= new RadioButton(this);

    radioGroup.addView(radioButton1);
    radioGroup.addView(radioButton2);
```

I hope this will help.